# How can I get rid of page margins using UIPrintInteractionController for Airprint

Tags: objective-c, margin, airprint, uiprintformatter

I am trying to AirPrint a UIImage using UIPrintInteractionController
this code works successfully except a margin is added to the print preview which is not desirable for me. how can I customize the left, right , top & bottom margins to zero or other values? i am aware of printablerect but how to modify it? Thanks for helps in advance:)

```
 UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController    sharedPrintController];
 NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageforPrint, 1.0);
 if (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: imageData] ) {
     pic.delegate = self;

     UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
     printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
     printInfo.jobName = @"Job 1";
     printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
     pic.printInfo = printInfo;

     UIPrintPageRenderer *renderer = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];

     UIPrintFormatter *Formatter = [[UIPrintFormatter alloc] init];
     Formatter=pic.printFormatter;
     Formatter.startPage=0;
     Formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

     Formatter.startPage=0;

     [renderer Formatter startingAtPageAtIndex: 0];

     pic.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers=YES;
     pic.printPageRenderer=renderer;

     pic.printFormatter=Formatter;
     pic.printingItem = imageData;
     pic.showsPageRange = YES;

     void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
                                ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
           //self.content = nil;
           if (!completed && error)
               NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %ld", error.domain, (long)error.code);

     };

     [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: Have you resolved this margin issue? Actually I am also getting this issue